# ARM atomics performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, arm, atomic, intel

I am running the same code on an Intel CPU and an ARM CPU (Mac/iOS, compiler: Clang). By profiling the application, I noticed, that on iOS/ARM the atomic operations are the top 3 items, while on Intel, they are not even in the top 10. Is that true, that on ARM atomic operations are *that much* slower? (relatively of course)

Comment: Herb Sutter's "atomic weapons" talks says that Arm7 and PowerPC are the reason why C++ has such an elabrate set of memory ordering options: On those architectures sequential consistency is very expensive, and you need to use relaxed orderings to get reasonable performance.

Comment: Wow thanks, that's insanely useful.

Comment: While Herb Sutter's talk is very interesting and enlightening it might not really adhere to the problem. You should provide some code and disassemblies for a better understanding.

Comment: comparing apples and oranges will only get you so far.  Depending on the benchmark an ARM system will be considerably faster, likewise an intel system will be considerably faster.  Pretty easy to demonstrate both.

Comment: *the **atomic operations** are the top 3 items*.  We need to see the code.  Atomic can mean so many things.  I guess you are talking about *Clang* C++ atomics from C++x11 such as [n2427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html).  Is *Clang/BSD* optimized for the x86, Is the C++ standard optimized for the x86 or is the x86 a better lock free CPU.  I guess the tools or your code are at fault.  We don't know the version of the tool and we don't even have your code.

Comment: I will have to run some tests, but the problem will be what @KerrekSB said I think. It does not matter whether I use the c++11 atomics, or the OSAtomic* calls, the result is the same. The code is the OpenCASCADE library, which you can access at opencascade.org, the problematic part is the Geom_BSpline curve evaluation algorithm. It is using the posix mutexes for synchronization, but I also tried it with the c++11 synchronization primitives, and with the dispatch API's high performance semaphores, the result was the same.

Comment: @dwelch I am not talking about absolute times, but relative times. I only say, that on ARM the CPU will spend the 30% of its time on performing atomic operations, while on intel it will be only ~1%.

Comment: if you say so...I think it depends on the implementation/code generated...for either platform...

Comment: @dwelch Here is a detailed profile view: http://imgur.com/GiW3LZ8

Comment: Ah, with a name like "OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64Barrier" it becomes a lot clearer. It's not the "Atomic" part that matters at all, it's the "Barrier" that'll make the big difference (and if you're single-threaded, using a mutex to protect yourself from yourself, is almost certainly completely unnecessary)

Comment: It is unnecessary in this case, but some other parts of the code are running in multiple threads where it is necessary. But yes, in this case, I could simply remove the mutexes.

Answer (score 3):

One point to note is that, thanks to implementation details, you're not necessarily seeing the whole story.

Under the load-linked/store-conditional paradigm of ARM, any atomic operation is at *least* 4 instructions - load-exclusive, <operation><sup>1</sup>, store-exclusive, conditional branch to retry if necessary. Every other core is entirely oblivious to this and carries on doing its own thing.

On x86, however, where instructions can operate directly on memory, atomics are typically accomplished by sticking the LOCK prefix on a single instruction. This means 2 things: firstly, you can never be interrupted *inside* your atomic 'routine' since it's a single instruction. Secondly, no other core can access memory while the bus is locked, so it effectively pauses execution of everything until it completes<sup>2</sup>. Together, these mean that a sampling profiler will rarely, if ever, catch the atomic operation 'in progress' regardless of how long it actually takes.

<sub>[1] OK, so that makes an atomic swap only 3 instructions, but anything else has one or more instructions in the middle here.</sub>

<sub>[2] This is slightly less true of modern cores which will only lock their own cache, rather than *everything*, to avoid affecting other cores accessing unrelated areas, but the hardware cache-coherency will still prevent anyone else interfering.</sub>

Comment: On x86 however the instructions are considerably longer than arm instructions (when a mem operand is used), are content with unaligned transfers, etc, are microcoded, etc.  The architectures are different and as a result you can never expect every line of high level code to perform the same across architectures and platforms, it is that simple.

Comment: Also, if excessive time spent in atomic routines is down to a lot of STREX failures in multiple threads, it's well worth investigating the reason for the contention. Data layout is important here - attempting simultaneous atomics on two variables in the same exclusive reservation granule (typically == cache line) could hurt performance badly.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think memory locking will be the problem,  because my application is running on a single thread. The atomics are called from mutexes, that are not necessary in my case, but they are present in the library, because it is implemented thread safe. Obviously I can simply remove those mutexes and recompile the lib, but I was curious what could cause that performance bottleneck.